# Is the runner on safe if the the fielder steps on the bag before him?

Tags: rules, baseball

Consider this case. Runner's on first, batter hits ground ball and reaches first base safely.  Runner on first advances to second, but fielder steps on the bag before him. Is the Runner safe or out?

Comment: Could you explain why you think this isn't a simple force out?

Answer (score 1):

The runner has been forced out at second. It is not considered a hit for the batter either.